# Exception on javac.deprecation while using Nutch on eclipse running on Windows

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

Hey I am trying to use Nutch Web Crawler on eclipse but getting error as shown here:

[image].

I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O54O6aepqSM&t=435s video to get start. kindly help me thank  you in advance